# Escape brackets within string

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I need to escape brackets within a file name. Currently I do this as follows:

```
$string = 'folder1/folder2/foldera/abc/myFile(2).jpg';

str_replace(')', '\)', str_replace('(', '\(', $string));

echo $string;

// outputs: folder1/folder2/foldera/abc/myFile\(2\).jpg
```

It is inefficient as this is executed within a loop of hundreds of results. Is there a better, cleaner more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Maybe `preg_quote()`?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to escape round bracket??

Comment: @Andrew it's because i'm outputting this within a data feed and the recipient requested the brackets to be escaped in this manner.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce one call to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), by using array.

```
str_replace(array(')', '('),  array('\)', '\('), $string);
```

**P.S. :**  Another option would be [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), but in your case you want to escape only `(` and `)`. And [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) will escape all `regex` characters.

Comment: As @jiboulex said `[]` is now equivalent to `array()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for preg_quote :

```
$string = preg_quote($string);
```

or something more like :

```
$string = str_replace([')', '('], ['\\)', '\\('], $string);
```

Comment: Since php5.4 you can declare your array with this short syntax : see there : http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$findstring = array('(',')');
$escpestring = array('\(','\)');
$string = 'folder1/folder2/foldera/abc/myFile(2).jpg';
$output = str_replace($findstring,$escpestring,$string);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a better function is `escapeshellcmd` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) which

> Following characters are preceded by a backslash: &#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$\, \x0A and \xFF. ' and " are escaped only if they are not paired. In Windows, all these characters plus % and ! are replaced by a space instead.